# How can I reset the i variable inside my for loop?

Tags: c#

```
 for (int k = 0; k < 32;k=k+1)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j < 32; j++)
            {
                double Score = (user0[k] * user0[j] + user1[k] * user1[j] + user2[k] * user2[j] + user3[k] * user3[j] + user4[k] * user4[j] + user5[k] * user5[j] + user6[k] * user6[j] + user7[k] * user7[j] + user8[k] * user8[j] + user9[k] * user9[j] + user10[k] * user10[j] + user11[k] * user11[j] + user12[k] * user12[j] + user13[k] * user13[j] + user14[k] * user14[j] + user15[k] * user15[j] + user16[k] * user16[j] + user17[k] * user17[j] + user18[k] * user18[j] + user19[k] * user19[j] + user20[k] * user20[j] + user21[k] * user21[j] + user22[k] * user22[j] + user23[k] * user23[j] + user24[k] * user24[j] + user25[k] * user25[j] + user26[k] * user26[j] + user27[k] * user27[j] + user28[k] * user28[j] + user29[k] * user29[j] + user30[k] * user30[j] + user31[k] * user31[j]) / ((Math.Sqrt(user0[k] * user0[k] + user1[k] * user1[k] + user2[k] * user2[k] + user3[k] * user3[k] + user4[k] * user4[k] + user5[k] * user5[k] + user6[k] * user6[k] + user7[k] * user7[k] + user8[k] * user8[k] + user9[k] * user9[k] + user10[k] * user10[k] + user11[k] * user11[k] + user12[k] * user12[k] + user13[k] * user13[k] + user14[k] * user14[k] + user15[k] * user15[k] + user16[k] * user16[k] + user17[k] * user17[k] + user18[k] * user18[k] + user19[k] * user19[k] + user20[k] * user20[k] + user21[k] * user21[k] + user22[k] * user22[k] + user23[k] * user23[k] + user24[k] * user24[k] + user25[k] * user25[k] + user26[k] * user26[k] + user27[k] * user27[k] + user28[k] * user28[k] + user29[k] * user29[k] + user30[k] * user30[k] + user31[k] * user31[k])) * (Math.Sqrt(user0[j] * user0[j] + user1[j] * user1[j] + user2[j] * user2[j] + user3[j] * user3[j] + user4[j] * user4[j] + user5[j] * user5[j] + user6[j] * user6[j] + user7[j] * user7[j] + user8[j] * user8[j] + user9[j] * user9[j] + user10[j] * user10[j] + user11[j] * user11[j] + user12[j] * user12[j] + user13[j] * user13[j] + user14[j] * user14[j] + user15[j] * user15[j] + user16[j] * user16[j] + user17[j] * user17[j] + user18[j] * user18[j] + user19[j] * user19[j] + user20[j] * user20[j] + user21[j] * user21[j] + user22[j] * user22[j] + user23[j] * user23[j] + user24[j] * user24[j] + user25[j] * user25[j] + user26[j] * user26[j] + user27[j] * user27[j] + user28[j] * user28[j] + user29[j] * user29[j] + user30[j] * user30[j] + user31[j] * user31[j])));

                if (Score > simScore)
                {
                    simScore = Score;
                }


            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("Score =" + simScore);
        }
```

I think you can ignore the long equation.
I need this program to compare 1 book to 32 other books.
The `for (int k = 0; k < 5;k=k+1)`loop is for the one selected book to be compared to 32 others (then give the greatest similarity rating).

The `for (int j = 1; j < 32; j++)` loop is to allow all the different books to be compared to the the book selected (book k).

The problem is that a book cannot be compared to itself because I think it ruins the equation and I get non-sensical values for the similarity ratings.
How can I omit a book?
(For example: When comparing k=3 (book 3) to other books, how can I make it so that j will not use the same reference?

Comment: Oh my goodness... Use 2D arrays man.

Comment: First, a book needs to have some identifier otherwise you won't be able to tell which book is which. Second, in your inner loop, you check the identifier of the current iterated book to see if it is identical to the current iterated book of the outer loop.

Comment: A simpley `if (j==i) continue;` might help

Comment: what is (SUMOF(UserN[k] * UserN[j]) / (Sqrt(POW(UserN[k],2) * (Sqrt(POW(UserN[j],2)))))) where N = 0 -> 31 ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the second loop from one past the first.  Comparing the pair (a,b) is the same as comparing (b,a), so you don't need to start from the beginning with each subsequent book.

```
   for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++)
   {
        for (var j = k + 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            ....
            // if you need the complete set, you can store both
            rating[j][k] = ...
            rating[k][j] = ...
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to put an if statement that only evaluates the body of the second loop if k != j. I'm not familiar with C#, so there may be other ways of doing it that I'm not aware of, but this is how I would do it in Python.

Comment: If you are not sure if this works for c#, then you should put it as comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about using continue?

```
for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        if (j == k)
            continue;

        // Compare
        if (isMatch)
            break;
    }
}
```